# how to Center align div if enough space otherwise right align

Tags: css

parent container => flexible width(width depends on browser window)

child div => fixed width of 900px (inside parent)

My requirement is

1. if width of parent is more than 900 then align child div in center
2. if width of parent is less than 900 then align child div to the right. Hence left portion will be truncated.

Is there any pure css solution?

Comment: Hem... why ? If your child is 900px, you don't have to center it or align it left or right... since it takes all the width !

Comment: is the parent container's width = to the browser window's width ?

Comment: You really should post your code and make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: parent is any div whose width is auto set. child's width is specified as 900px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [fiddled](http://jsfiddle.net/7TGeq/9/) it a little.

you basically need this, am I right?

```
#parent{
    background-color: blue;
    overflow: hidden;
    direction:rtl;
}

.child{
    width:900px;   
    float:right;
    margin: 0 auto;
    direction:ltr;
}
```

So direction to align the divs without making the child div float to the walls, and another direction inside child to not mess up the contents inside. margin: 0 auto; to center the div and overflow:hidden to truncate.

EDIT: Try it now.

Comment: Thanks! its working now. So direction rtl seems to do the magic. I have seen in fiddle that float is no longer needed

Answer (score 1):

you can try with media query..

For example:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 900px) {
   .div { margin: 0px auto }
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 900px) {
   .div { float: left; }
}
```

You can try to combine css with that...

Comment: Thanks for giving new info which I may need in future. For this one direction works and it is also works on IE.

Answer (score 1):

```
parent {direction:rtl}
child {direction:ltr;}
```

Basicly, `overflow` will scroll from right to left or will hide left side if `hidden`;

test and play with it here :) : http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/GHCne

Comment: Thanks so much. this works! I can't accept multiple answers so I voted up your answer :)

Comment: No problem as long as you get your answer. It's an old trick that use to work too to switch side of vertical scrollbar (it doesn't anymore :) for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)?

You'll just want to make sure they're [supported](http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries) in all the browsers you're targeting.